# Moving javascript down dynamically in page.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I want to [submit form](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ariefbayu/3697293/raw/7a87d033ee1adb51be20636daadb7a3cc540be49/phantomjs-facebook-update.js) with phantomjs. Page is written in React, so form [doesn't render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739605/getelementbyid-returns-null) at execution time.

I want to [exchange all javascript in loaded page, moving it to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423528/getting-typeerror-document-getelementbyid-is-null-when-using-react-js-wi) - so then it will be possible to getelementbyid input. 
How to do this?

Comment: Please outline details in question itself and only use links as support for those details. We shouldn't have to assimilate what is in multiple links to figure out your full issue. Questions should be self contained

Comment: Did you try using  setTimeout?

Comment: yes i tried doLogin with setTimeout 20000 - same error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) lifecycle method of your react component. To access the actual DOM node of your component you can do something like `const $component = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));`

in react <0.14 you can access the DOM node by calling `this.getDOMNode()`